# Push data to dataLayer in thankyou page woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

this code should push data to datalayer in thankyou page but instead i found the code snippet is printed in the page as it is, what could be the issue

```
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'purchase_tracking');
    function purchase_tracking($order_id){ ?>
       $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
       $currency = $order->get_order_currency();
       $total = $order->get_total(); ?>
           <script>
        dataLayer.push({
           'conversionValue': <?php echo $total ?>,
           'currency': '<?php echo $currency ?>',
           'transactionId': '<?php echo $order_id ?>'
        });
       </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this? if yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
function mv_conversion_script( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    
    // Get the Customer billing email
    $billing_email  = $order->get_billing_email();

    // Get the Customer billing phone
    $billing_phone  = $order->get_billing_phone();

    ?>
    <script>
        dataLayer.push({
            'phone': '<?php echo $billing_phone ?>',
            'email': '<?php echo $billing_email ?>'
        });     
    </script>
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'mv_conversion_script' );
```